# How can I use `!GetAtt` in serverless.yml default value operator?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have serverless.yml which is to deploy a dynamodb and a lambda function. The lambda function needs to reference the dynamodb table stream arn.

```yaml
functions:
  onStreamHandler:
    handler: ...
    name: ...
    events:
      - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        arn: ${opt:dbStreamArn, !GetAtt EntityTable.StreamArn}
```

In the `arn:` field, I'd like to specify if `dbStreamArn` is not specified from command line parameter, get the value from `EntityTable.StreamArn`. But I got this error:

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  Missing "arn" property for stream event in function "onStreamHandler" The correct syntax is: stream: <StreamArn> OR an object with an "arn" property. Please check the docs for more info.
```

what is the right way to reference the arn value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because cloud formation is trying to create your lambda before your dynamodb table.

To fix this, add `dependsOn` to your lambda function e.g:

```
functions:
  onStreamHandler:
    handler: ...
    name: ...
    events:
      - stream:
        type: dynamodb
        arn: ${opt:dbStreamArn, !GetAtt EntityTable.StreamArn}
    dependsOn:
      - EntityTable
```

This will deploy the function once the the `EntityTable` has been deployed. `!GetAtt EntityTable.StreamArn` should then resolve correctly.